# DynamoDB / ApiGateWay UpdateItem method returning serializedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Quite new to AWS / DynamoDB. I'm trying to make a UpdateItem method work on my API. I have a Resource with the path `x/users/update/{wallet}` with wallet being the key.

In here I set a UpdateItem method just like I have all my other `Query` / `Scan` / `PutItem` methods. this has the following mapping template:

```
{
    "TableName": "Users",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "wallet = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('wallet')"
        }
        ":v2": {
            "S": $input.json('$.username')
        }
    }
    "UpdateExpression": "set username = :v2",
    "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
}
```

This returns a 200 with `"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"`

Pretty sure this is related to my Mapping template but can't figure out what. Looked at the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html and think I used the `Sample Request` in there as a template to test it like this

```
{
    "TableName": "Users",
    "Key": {
        "wallet": {
            "S": "$input.params('wallet')"
        },
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET username = :val1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":val1": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.username')"
        },
    },
    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

payload is just as simple as

```
{"username":"test"}
```

but that gives the same result.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong here?

Cheers!

EDIT:
PutItem looks like this:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Users",
    "Item": {
        "userId": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
        },
        "date": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.date')"
        },
        "wallet": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.wallet')"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is the answer but in your update expression set might be case sensitive and you might need SET

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro Unfortunately not, gave it a try tho, could of been!

Comment: Can you share which SDK you're using please? Can you also share the `PutItem` command that already works please?

Comment: @Rafet Added, also no SDK! Just using the console.aws.amazon.com!

Comment: Thank you! Can you also tell me which field is your Partition Key? Do you have a Sort Key as well?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not accessing the record to update with the key of your table. Unlike SQL, you cannot access a record to update with any field in DynamoDB. You have to use your key depending on how you defined it (`PK` or `PK + SK`).

Given that you have both PK and SK defined, you need them both in your key input. Together they form a composite primary key. The below input should work for you.

```
{
    "TableName": "Users",
    "Key": {
        "wallet": {
            "S": "$input.params('wallet')"
        },
        "date": {
            "S": "$input.params('date')"
        },
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET username = :val1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":val1": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.username')"
        },
    },
    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

Comment: The partition key is actually `wallet` which then comes to the same answer as one in the example. Sorry should of clarified this was a `putItem` example of another table.

Comment: No worries. Have you got a Sort Key on the `Users` table? Also, have you got a `putItem` example handy for the `Users` table?

Comment: Yes! Updated the putItem in the question to represent the `Users` table. The sorting key is `date`

Comment: I see. Given that you have an SK as well, you need to pass it through as part of your request. PK and SK form a composite key when both defined. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I don't think that works. The URL in this case is users/update/123, 123 being `input.params('wallet')` adding date to this url doesn't make sense. Also tried adding it to the body instead but this returns the same `serializedException`

Comment: It's worth trying removing `123` from the URL and getting both params from the body. Also, what is the type of `wallet`? Is it a number or a string?

Comment: I'll give it a try, wallet is a string!

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. Isn't there a place to debug this? Feels very tough to debug like this, no error messages or anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251958/discussion-between-rafet-and-wesley-van-s).

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-Key) takes a `Key` not a `KeyConditionExpression`

This one below is correct:

```
{
"TableName": "Users",
"Key": {
    "wallet": {
        "S": "$input.params('wallet')"
    },
},
"UpdateExpression": "SET username = :val1",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":val1": {"S": "$input.params('$.username')"},
},
"ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

You also state your payload is simply

`{"username":"test"}`

You must also specify `wallet` as this is the key

Comment: Actually the wallet is defined in the url as {wallet} path so this doesn't need to be in the body. However I see both use .params which shouldn't be the case. I'll update the question.